# I have a button in my react app that i only want it to be pressed once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented this onclick event in it and I want the functions inside the onclick event to run once

```
    <button className='btn2' onClick={() => {

OpenForm();

      if (IsLoggedIn === true){
        Like();
    }else if(IsLoggedIn === false){
    return;
    }
      }}>
```

Comment: and it's not working ? what's happening ?

Comment: it is working but I want to only call the onclick event once so I run the functions inside of it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want users to be able to press the button only once and then disable it after it was pressed, you can try this:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

function MyComponent() { 

    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        IsLoggedIn && Like();
        IsLoggedIn && setDisabled(true);
    };

    return (
        <>
            ...
            <button disabled={disabled} onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
            ...
        </>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is keep track of that using state, let's say a `hasClicked`, the default state will be false and you changed that in the onClick handler you have up there, an example code snippet would be like:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [hasClicked, setHasClicked] = useState(false)
    ...

    const btnClickHandler = () => {
        ...
        setHasClicked(true)
        ...
    }

    return (
        <button disabled={hasClicked} onClick={btnClickHandler}>Click<button/>
    )
}
```

That way, the button will be disabled once the user clicks on it because `disabled` will now be pointing to a true `hasClicked` value.